# Proxmox : 8 SAS (Data) and 2 SSD (OS) Setup (SW/HW RAID and VMs)

Tags: raid, virtual-machine, lvm, zfs, proxmox

I'm noob on homelab and server setup, that's why I'm calling to your support

Bellow is the main list of my server's components :

- CPU : 1 x Intel Xeon Silver 4208
- RAM : 5 x 16Gb DDR4 ECC
- RAID Card : Lenovo 930-8i 2gb flash
- HW Raid 1 (is it OK?) for OS : 2 x 1Tb SSD SATA
- HW Raid 6 (is it OK ?) for DATA :8 x 4Tb Toshiba SAS 12Gb 7200Rpm
- Network : In addition to the 3 x 1Gb RJ45 - 1 x LOM Card with 2 1Gb output

With my server I need to :

- Share private and cloud data for my family
- Make Home automation with Home assistant OS
- Create a Discord / Teamspeak server or somethings like that for my child
- (Maybe) Create a free gameserver

I read a lot of post about Raid settings, especially the following post which one was really interesting to read : [RAID5 - ZFS vs LVM+mdadm on 3 SSDs for KVM/LXC server (proxmox)](https://serverfault.com/q/925730/1013323)

Could you help me to setup my Proxmox VE server please ?

Comment: What is the problem? Proxmox team even made videos with step-by-step instructions, if you want these.

Comment: You can find the answers to most of your questions if you read thru the entire openzfs documentation. RAID is not recommended under ZFS, in general ZFS should be as bare-metal as possible because it handles volumes and everything at its level above the hardware. We can't help you setup Proxmox, read the documentation there is a setup guide for debian bullseye as well.